# controlling width of options inside select element

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a select element with a certain width. My question is how can I control the width of the options using angular so that they will be the same width as the select bar, regarding their input length?
I am using ng-select to set the options.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Regular option", "Long option number 1", "Very very long option that doent mke sense"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names" style="width: 180px">
</select>
</div>

<p>This example shows how to fill a dropdown list using the ng-options directive.</p>

</body>
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added a code example that describes my issue.

Comment: Select Option element is controlled by the browsers and very little to no control in css. even if you did, there will be inconsistencies with respect to browsers as UI of Chrome, firefox, IE, IE Edge, and Safari are different. I do not think you will be able to handle it even if you did so I do not think the effort is worth it. Instead create a custom select option with ul li's which you can control well.

Comment: Yes I have read about this problem, I just assumed that there is a solution built in angular... Thanks for the proposed solution, sounds like it might work

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the width from the style on select element (`style="width: 180px"`)

See below Snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Regular option", "Long option number 1", "Very very long option that doent mke sense"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
</select>
</div>

<p>This example shows how to fill a dropdown list using the ng-options directive.</p>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I intended to set the width of the select bar. What I want is that the option element will match the width of the select bar, not the other way around.